# Http Get and post calls in android

Tags: android, http-get, httpservice

I am doing a http GET service call.
I can see the data coming in chrome rest client, but I am getting error reply as follow

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
<title>406 - Client browser does not accept the MIME type of the requested page.</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;background:#EEEEEE;}
fieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;} 
h1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;}
h2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;} 
h3{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#000000;} 
#header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-family:"trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;color:#FFF;
background-color:#555555;}
#content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;}
.content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;}
-->
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header"><h1>Server Error</h1></div>
<div id="content">
 <div class="content-container"><fieldset>
<h2>406 - Client browser does not accept the MIME type of the requested page.</h2>
<h3>The page you are looking for cannot be opened by your browser because it has a file name extension that your browser does not accept.</h3>
</fieldset></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

URL which I am passing to getData.

http://ec2-50-19-105-251.compute-1.amazonaws.com/ad/Upload/getitemlist09122013014749.txt

My getData()::

```
public static String getData(String url) throws CustomException {
    // http post
    InputStream is = null;
    StringBuilder sb = null;
    String result = null;
    HttpGet httppost;

    try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        httppost = new HttpGet(url);
        httppost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();
        Log.e("log_tag", "connection success ");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection" + e.toString());
        throw new CustomException("Could not establish network connection");
    }

    // convert response to string
    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int c;
        byte buffer[] = new byte[1024];
        while ((c = is.read(buffer)) > -1)
            baos.write(buffer, 0, c);
        byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();

        is.close();
        result = new String(data, 0, data.length, "utf-8");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        throw new CustomException("Error parsing the response");
    }

    return result;

}
```

please help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You explicitly set `httppost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");` which means that you only accept json as response. Most probably the server is trying to send you a reponse that it is not a json so it signals with 406.
If you remove the `httppost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json")` you may try to see what is the raw response and adjust the "Accept" header accordingly.

EDIT: reposnse from the server is `text/plain` so changing the "Accept" to "text/plain" will do the job

Comment: Yes you are correct. After hiding those lines I receive data but, Now getting OutOfMemory Exception in while loop. 
I think the text file is more that the byte array size. Also I have tested by putting 10240 bytes. Getting the same exception.
Please suggest me what to do.

Comment: Can't you just use `result = EntityUtils.toString(entity);` instead of the whole streams/buffer thing?

Comment: It should be called instead of `is = entity.getContent();`. Did you placed it there?

Comment: sorry I don't know that. Now I have hidden that line and run the code. Getting the same result. OutOfMemory Exception. :(